# Optimizing Painting video encoding in Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I want to create live painting video as export feature for a painting application.

I can create a video with a series of images, with the use of a library ( FFMPEG or MediaCodec). But, this would require too much processing power to compare the images and encode the video.

While drawing, I know exactly which pixels are changed. So, I can save lot of processing if I can pass this info to FFMPEG, instead of having the FFMPEG figure this out from the images.

Is there away to efficiently encode the video for this purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

It should not require "too much processing power" for MediaCodec. Because, for example, device is capable to write video in real time, some of them write full HD video.
There's another thing : each MediaCodec's encoder requires pixel data in specific format, you should query API for supported capabilities before using the API. Also it will be tricky to make your app work on all devices with MediaCodec if your app produces only one pixel format, because probably not all of devices will support it(another words: different vendors have different MediaCodec implementation).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did check MediaCodec before.
But, There are no android CTS for MediaCodec for encode before 4.2, and every device manufacturer implemented it on their own way.

Comment: Android 4.3 (API 18), actually.  It introduced Surface input to MediaCodec, which avoids the need to support multiple YUV formats for input, and added the CTS tests that give some assurance of cross-device compatibility.  (See http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ .)